# Minimizing a function with simplex using constraint in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I currently have a function that take a lot of parameters (let's call them 
**lot*, *a*, *b*), do a lot of stuff and return 3 float (*x*, *y* , *z*).
What I'm trying to do is to minimize *x* by varying *a* and *b* and puting some constraint to *a*, *b*, *y* and *z* (*a* and *b* are limited with a min and a max value while *y* and *z* just have a min value).

If I just explore my search area I can see that the surface that form all the *x* is in fact a bowl, so my result is linear (or am I that wrong?) if my result is linear I can just use a simplex to find my minimum allowed with my constraint (or Am i wrong here?).

Now my problem: In python, using optimize.minimize from scipy it seems that I can't use constraint with simplex (except maybe min and max on *a* and *b* but that's not the biggest issue here) so did I misunderstand completly the minimize function? Do I really need something else than simplex or is there another solution than the optimize function?

Here is some kind of code snippet that can emulate my function:

```
# coding=utf-8


def bowl(a,b):

    y = a*b
    z = a/b
    x = (a*a)/(y*y) + (b*b)/(z*z)

    return x,y,z


def surface(min_a, max_a, min_b, max_b):

    for a in range(min_a,max_a):
        buffer = list()
        for b in range(min_b, max_b):
            buffer.append(bowl(a,b))
        print(buffer)
surface(1,10,1,10)
```

Comment: It is a code problem because (a) you’re asking about limitations of a library function, and (b) without it, your constraints and question as a whole are unclear.

Comment: You mean without my code? Should I try to post some code snippet that emulate my issue?

Comment: Yes, edit it into your question. You may want to look at [ask].

Comment: Simplex is for linear equations—and particularly, for linear equations over continuous variables. That's not what you have. `a` and `b` take on discrete values. You need to define an objective function and minimize it. But `minimize` doesn't use simplex anyway. You would benefit more from an online tutorial (or reading the `minimize` docs) than a question-and-answer site like this.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I found some way to make it work with COBYLA, so it's something, another question though: I made a model of my algorithm on excell, with all the calculation and I used the solver to minimize it, and it worked, but the algorithm that excell use (or at least the algorithm microsoft claim to use) is a simplex, with constraint and all. That's probably why I was confuse in the first place by the way. But in this case what does excell really do / really use?

Comment: No “another thing”. That’s not how SO works. Post it as a separate question, and link to this one if needed.